# É possível Implementar uma classe abstrata em PHP sem a necessidade de herança como em Java?

Tags: php, java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, classes-abstratas

É possível efetuar em PHP "da mesma forma" a instancia da classe `CachorroAbstract` no método `main` abaixo:

```
public abstract class CachorroAbstract {
    public abstract void latir();
}
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CachorroAbstract cachorro = new CachorroAbstract() { //AQUI
            @Override
            public void latir() {
                 System.out.println("AU! AU!");
            }
        };
        cachorro.latir();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use interface :)

Comment: Olá diegofm, obrigado pela resposta. Na verdade minha classe em php possui alguns métodos implementados, fiz esse em java para ser bem breve, e esses métodos implementados fazem uso dos retornos dos métodos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sem herança é impossível. Mas não precisa usar uma classe para instanciar depois, se estiver usando PHP 7. Em versões anteriores não dá. Até teria outro tipo de técnica sem usar orientação a objeto, mas não é o que deseja.

[Em PHP 7 é possível](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) com a sintaxe `new class extends`. Isso é chamado classe anônima em ambas linguagens. Algo assim:

```
$cachorro = new class extends CachorroAbstract { ... };
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/ExtendClassForObject.php).

Comment: Olá bigown, Obrigado pela resposta! Acredito que não poderei utilizar PHP 7, mas mesmo assim, muito obrigado pela informação!

Comment: É, isto é uma complicação :)